# f# type providers: build from powerpack fails?

Tags: msbuild, f#, type-providers

If one looks at the (\compiler\3.0\Sep2012\src\fsharp\FSharp.Data.Typeproviders) FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.fsproj in http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70537#1231021 it seems somewhat shady to say...

```
<Import Project="$(FSharpSourcesRoot)\fs2Sharp.Data.TypeProviders\FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.Shared.fsproj"  
          Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' 25' AND 
                    '$(TargetFramework)' 23-wp' " />
  <ItemGroup>                             2
    <!--This is used for compiling the run2ype provider DLL for WP7, Silverlight etc. -->
    <!--This is the only file used. -->
```

Especially the line with `<ItemGroup>                             2`... In addition I would guess that the part " the run2ype provider " also indicates some errors.

Trying to fix this manually is not that easy it seems since I do believe there are more errors in this file.

I have built all other stuff (compiler etc.) according to instructions, but building these other libs are not very easy.

Have anyone been able to manage to build all including type providers? If yes: How? Does anyone have any instructions?

Comment: Have you tried building it from https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp instead? It incorporates the latest code from codeplex and it doesn't have that extra 2 that's causing the problem on that file

Comment: @ovatsus dont think so. same shait, new wrapping. just the "2" removed as you notice. no compile though.